# TFS 15rc2 Build Tab hanging in Browser

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

Build Tab for vnext in Browser hanging in refresh After a co worker deleted my Builds. Only works if I switch to queued Builds and hitting refresh couple of Times. Any one Else having Same Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue. I tried to delete a build in TFS 15 RC2, but neither the browser refreshed nor the build was deleted:

[image]

I have reported a bug at website below, you can vote it:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3105465

---

**Update:**

Please check the response in the feedback:

> Try selecting the row first before deleting (if it's the same bug, not
>   sure if bug exists in RC2, but this should be fixed in TFS Dev15 RTM).
>   If it doesn't work, please open F12, to see if there are any errors
>   from rest calls.